# What is the default connection pool of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, tomcat8, openjpa

We have a spring-based web app which uses spring-data-jpa and openjpa with PostgreSQL DB. The EntityManager settings as below.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
          <prop key="openjpa.ConnectionURL">jdbc:postgresql://${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.database}</prop>
          <prop key="openjpa.ConnectionUserName">${db.username}</prop>
          <prop key="openjpa.ConnectionPassword">${db.password}</prop>
          <prop key="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As we have given the jpaProperties and org.postgreql.Drive only, the web app is running on tomcat8. What is the default connection pool will be used for this case?

- org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource
- org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
- org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool

If we want to give a dataSource bean in this case, which connection pool is the best practice?

Comment: I doubt if there is any default. It will not use a connection pool unless you using spring boot.

Comment: You are not setting the properties on the Spring bean but rather on the JPA provider directly (notice that all the connection related properties you are setting begin with `openjpa.`). By default OpenJPA does not use a connection pool but from v2.1.0 onwards you can activate Apache DBCP which comes bundled with OpenJPA. See the [OpenJPA documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/faq.html#pooling) for details on configuring the bundled or a third-party connection pool.